# Arch ARM set timezone

Tags: timezone, arch-arm

I have installed Arch Linux on my Raspberry Pi from rasparch-exton-1680mb-180402.zip, successfully updated and have set my Locale to en_AU.UTF-8 and this looks OK.

timedatectl continues to show Time zone: UTC

`timedatectl set-timezone AEDT` returns Invalid time zone

Comment: `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Sydney /etc/localtime`

Comment: @jasonwryan the link seems to have made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reading of `man timedatectl` I found the list-timezones command.

I set `timedatectl set-timezone Australia/Sydney`